# iCloud capabilities in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

Planning to add iCloud support for our application. Tried to switch on iCloud from Capabilities. While doing it I get following result[image]

The identifier which is not available is what my identifier. Tried to resolve issue by hitting Fix issue button but nothing happens.  If i try build the app I get following error 
[image]

How to resolve this. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to enable iCloud for your appid, similar like you do for Push Notifications.

Comment: have done it. Generated a new profile. Still issue occurs

Comment: Have you tried to use `Fix Issue` option? It actually fixes the problem by contacting your developer account.

Comment: if I hit it app freezes for a while. and issue remains same.

Comment: Did you recheck the Provisioning Profile section after hitting `Fix Issue`, that might have been reset, you need to set that up again.

Comment: After restarting xcode fixissue creates appid as per my bundle identifier and creates profile also. but i want my application to be build in specific profile